# Decompiling APK: Changing Server URL

Tags: mongodb, apk

I have the following problem: three years ago, I did an android project which was working fine until now. I used a MongoDB server on mLab, missed the deadline and now it does not work anymore. So the plan is to migrate the data to my own VServer, which is not a problem.

However: I lost the android project. The only thing I have is the APK and I need to change a single URL to something else. I decompiled the APK, tried to find the URL in it, but no luck. I cannot find the string "ds125502.mlab.com" anywhere in the project and I do not really understand why this is the case. The decompiled APK consists of ".smali" and ".xml" files and i dont think there is any binaries inside which might have the URL(still unreadable and therefore not changeable) in them.

So basically: I need to change the URL which is somewhere in the APK file and wonder if this even is possible.

I am pretty desperate and do not expect very much from this post but well..I need a solution. Otherwise I'll have to redo the whole project which is not THAT much work but still 30 hours or so.

Comment: I feel very sorry for your loss!
Have you heard of git? Try using it within your project!

Comment: Aren't apk files signed or at least checksummed and therefore not editable?

Comment: I honestly do not know that much about it, but the tool I am using has a decompile and compile function

Comment: Consider posting your story on r/tifu. Wish you good luck!